# Tensorflow Keras logging steps in for loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, logging, stdout

I'm running someone else's program so I can't be 100% open about the code.
I'm using `load_model` from `tensorflow.keras.model` to load an `h5` model, then `model.predict(<data>)` in a `for loop`.

I'm also using `tqdm` to display a progress Bar. Now the problem is that as soon as I get to the loop, my console start printing output every new line:

[image]

I tried to block this output:

```py
import absl.logging
import logging
import os

os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
absl.logging.set_verbosity(absl.logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").setLevel(logging.ERROR)
logging.getLogger("tensorflow").addHandler(logging.NullHandler(logging.ERROR))
```

But nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it: according to `tensorflow.keras.model` documentation, the method `predict` has attributes `verbose` and `steps`: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

However, the same documentation suggest to use the `__call__` method when used in a loop: `model(<data>, training=False)` which does not output any steps.